# Razor - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Decimal) Does not Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having an issue where @Html.DisplayFor does not render the values in the browser when the model property is a decimal. Note the double types do display correctly. The other weird thing is that the do display once I promote the code to the production server...so this is just an issue on my local laptop.

Here is the model I am testing:

```
    public decimal Test { get { return (decimal)105.35;} }
    public decimal? TestNullable { get { return (decimal)105.35; } }
    public double TestDbl { get { return 105.35; } }
    public double? TestNullableDbl { get { return 105.35; } }
```

Here is the markup:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Test)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestNullable)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestDbl)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestNullableDbl)
```

And here is what is rendered in the html:

```
            <br>

            <br>
            105.35
            <br>
            105.35
```

Note that a double displays

Comment: Do you have a partial view located at DisplayTemplates/Decimal.cshtml? It'll try using that if you do... otherwise it falls back to a few default templates defined in the framework.

Comment: Thanks John but no. My DisplayTemplates folder is empty. I do have an editor template...but that shouldn't affect it.

Comment: You might have an object.cshtml too, I think it'll try using that as well. Prob not but just checking...

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new MVC 4 project from scratch to test and was unable to replicate your issue.  Given this, there must be something not quite right with your local configuration (mismatched assemblies vs what is installed on the server, a display template named decimal, a class named decimal, it really is unclear without more info)

Using VS 2013, .NET 4.5, Windows 8.1 64bit

**View Model**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public decimal Test { get { return (decimal)105.35; } }
    public decimal? TestNullable { get { return (decimal)105.35; } }
    public double TestDbl { get { return 105.35; } }
    public double? TestNullableDbl { get { return 105.35; } }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new TestViewModel());
        }

    }
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h2>Home</h2>
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Test)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestNullable)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestDbl)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestNullableDbl)
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<body>


<h2>Home</h2>
105.35
<br />
105.35
<br />
105.35
<br />
105.35

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Tommy for all that work you did. I don't have any display templates set up nor a class called decimal. And if that were the case would most likely cause the same issue on the production server I'd think. So it must be something else. Any ideas on how to test further or look for?

Comment: @ChadRichardson I wish I had more suggestions for you, but I have a feeling it is going to be an environment issue and not a MVC framework issue :/